# DB Schema password from Password Server on WebLogic App server (DB Pool)

Tags: security, jpa, weblogic, weblogic12c, password-protection

We would like to hide the Database Schema Passwords from WebLogic administrators because the database contains high secured data.

I am trying to find an official Oracle way how to define a Connection Pool where the password is read from an external Password Server but I have not found anything on the internet.

Can Weblogic communicate with Password Servers (eg. [Pleasant](https://pleasantsolutions.com/info/pleasant-password-server/m-programmatic-access/restful-api/api-examples/)) in order to read passwords of DB connections from external "secret" store?

**UPDATE 1**

Of course, we can write Java code which reads passwords from an external secret store and creates Connection Pool on a programmatic way but this seems for me as a big hack.

**UPDATE 2**

I also checked JPA and Hibernate documentation. I cannot see any official way to configure a JPA data source this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create and use a Wallet as described in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCA/oraclewallet.htm#JDBCA596).
Enjoy !